# Как при наведении на  обьект изменить свойства другого?

Tags: css3, css

Если они соседи, то можно с помощью (~). А если они один находится во втором? Или вообще не рядом?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В css можно менять - следующий в том-же уровне вложенности (+) любой из следующих в том-же уровне вложенности (~) непосредственного потомка ">" и любого потомка " ", родителей и предыдущие элементы менять нельзя.

вот памятка

html:

```
<div class="hoverme">Наведи на меня
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div><div class="test"></div> </div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
<hr/>
<div class="test"></div>
```

css:

```
div {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.test:before {
    content: "не навёл";
}
.hoverme:hover  .test:before {
    content: " я внук";
}
.hoverme:hover > .test:before {
    content: "> я детё";
}

.hoverme:hover ~ .test:before {
    content: "~ я сосед";
}

.hoverme:hover + .test:before {
    content: "+ я следующий";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h9JGb/

Answer (score 2):

[javascript-ом](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/z65nL/2/) можете на все dom-дерево влиять.